# PHP url create from string

Tags: php, regex, url

I would like to check a string and convert all the substrings that could be potential links inside the original string like http://www.google.com, or www.google.com, replaced with
`<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>` so that i can create real links from them.

How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I linkify urls in a string with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507436/how-do-i-linkify-urls-in-a-string-with-php)

Comment: @alexn: Not quite, as Alexander wants to also linkify URLs without `http://`.

Comment: @Tim Fair enough, then i recommend Alexander to look at the solution in this answer and modify it as needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113840/php-remove-url-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the HTML links by calling the following function in PHP:

```
$stringToCheck = 'http://www.google.com, or www.google.com';
$stringWithHTMLLinks = '';

$stringWithHTMLLinks = preg_replace('/\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/si', '<a href="\0">\0</a>', $stringToCheck);
```

Comment: the h*ttp://www.google.com works fine but the www.google.com gives me http://localhost/migo2/www.google.com on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex provided on [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) to match an URL.

Comment: i'll be sure to check it out :)

Comment: Here is the full version (IT IS LONG): `(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))`

Comment: Here is the shortened version (only matching http addresses): `(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))`

Comment: Also from Daring Fireball's page above: `Update: A few readers have asked what the licensing terms are for using this pattern in their own code. This pattern is free for anyone to use, no strings attached. Consider it public domain.`