# Return URLS from php string

Tags: php, string, url

I have an PHP array of strings it looks like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow consectetur adipiscing elit.
    [2] => Phasellus tempor vehicula fringilla. www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8
    [3] => google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8 Aenean in cursus libero.
);
```

URLs will be all sorts of forms, what I need is an array of those links. Something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow
    [2] => http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8
    [3] => http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8
);
```

Comment: Do you think that nobody has ever in the history of the internet had to parse URLs from strings, and that the code to do so has never been shared? Good news! It's been done, and the code has been shared, several thousand times! Head to your nearest search box.

Comment: Duplicate.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113840/php-remove-url-from-string

This will be helpful.

Comment: Neither a string beginning with "google.com" nor with "www.google.com" is a valid URL. It will be difficult and fuzzy to extract all possible variations. IMO you should first ensure that the URLs are valid.

Comment: I have tried using regular expression witch supposed to remove URLs with preg_match function but noting good came out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for you:

```
$pattern = '/((https?|ftp)\:(\/\/)|(file\:\/{2,3}))?(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(((([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.)?)+)(\.)(com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|[a-z]{2}))([\/][\/a-zA-Z0-9\.]*)*([\/]?(([\?][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\=][a-zA-Z0-9\%\(\)]*)([\&][a-zA-Z0-9]+[\=][a-zA-Z0-9\%\(\)]*)*))?/';

$a = array(
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow consectetur adipiscing elit.',
    'Phasellus tempor vehicula fringilla. www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8',
    'google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=utf-8 Aenean in cursus libero.',
);

$urls = array();

foreach($a as $line)
{
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $line, $match))
        continue;

    $urls[] = $match[0];
}

var_dump($urls);
```

The regular expression was taken from [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=ultimate%20url%20regexp) and corrected a bit.

Comment: I have tested this script and found few weak spots. It gets stuck with special symbols like - or _ or ? and does not handle well if url ends .something (except .html)

Answer (score 0):

You should write a proper regular expression to achieve this. Have a look at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html)