# Removing url / domain from string with parentheses

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

Is there any way to find and remove the url or domain from given string with parentheses ?

example:  (like someurl.com) should be (like) and [like someurl.com] to become [like] ... also [like someurl.com/path/something.html] should be [like]

maybe someone can help me with a code to do this.

Comment: regex is what you are looking for

Comment: Try using `preg_replace()`. I see your tag, but what have you tried?

Comment: i managed to replace url/domain from string but i can't do it on parentheses ...

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427530/regular-expression-pattern-to-match-url-with-or-without-http-www)

Comment: i use this code for string replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113840/php-remove-url-from-string but it only replace what is outside of ( ) and [ ] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) (regx) here

```
$string_with_url = 'lorem (like GOoogle.COM someurl.com/path/something.html ) lipsum';

$string_without_url = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.+[a-zA-Z\/]\s)?/", "", $string_with_url);

echo $string_without_url; // lorem (like ) lipsum
```

Comment: This works great on lowercase domains, uppercase ones are not replaced, or if an domain is : someDomain.com is replacing only omain.com and it will becode someD

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "(like someurl.com)";
$index_dot =  $index_space_before_dot = $index_after_dot = -1;
for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
    if($str[$i] == '.'){
        $index_dot = $i;
    }

    if($str[$i] == ' '  && $index_dot == -1 && $index_space_before_dot == -1){
        $index_space_before_dot = $i;
    }elseif ($str[$i] == ' '  && $index_dot > -1){
        $index_space_before_dot = $i;
    }
}

$str = substr($str, 0, $index_space_before_dot);
echo $str . ')';
```